# Can you deallocate functions in C++?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I was recently told that functions cannot be deallocated, but after-all they are instructions that do take some memory right? Just like how Constructors and Destructors work. So is there a way to deallocate functions?

Comment: Regular functions are not dynamically allocated in memory, so you cannot deallocate them

Comment: You cannot write self-modifying code in C++.

Comment: [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Why do you want to deallocate a function? Maybe there is a way to solve your actual problem in a different way. You can set up a dynamic container of callables.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen not in *standard* C++, but one can certainly call into the host OS to perform that kind of tricks. Not that one should.

Comment: You *can* write self modifying code in C++ but that's not what he asks. Functions, even if part of a class, are static. The only way to remove code from memory is by using a dynamically loaded library.

Comment: Perhaps the underlying (XY) question is "What does _deallocate_ mean in C++?"

Comment: If memory is low, operating systems that use virtual memory can unmap code that hasn't been used recently from memory. So in a way this will be done automatically for you.

Comment: Loading and unloading a library built as a shared-library/DLL allocates and deallocates memory for all the code (functions) and data (global and static variables) in the library at once. This is not a standard C++ feature, but one which is OS-specific and language-agnostic.

Comment: This is something that computers can do, but C++ compilers can't (except for shared libraries)

Comment: Windows, for example, is perfectly happy to let you VirtualAlloc a page, write some code to that page, VirtualProtect it to allow execution, and then call the code you just wrote.

Answer (score 6):

A great deal of program memory is allocated "statically" (executable code, global variables, constants); i.e. mapped once for all and claimed from the system at load time. They stay allocated during the whole program lifetime and there is nothing you can do.

Large heap space and stack space are also preallocated, but can be extended as required. Dynamically allocated variables as well as automatic ones are indeed created and deleted on demand during program allocation, but that does not necessarily mean that the "memory consumption" decreases, as the heap and stack spaces are always there.

Note that constructors and destructors do not allocate any memory, they just perform the initialization and de-initialization tasks. Allocation/deallocation is performed upon function entry/exit, on the stack, or upon invocation of new/delete, on the heap.

---

In fact, things are more complicated, as the memory space of a process is virtualized, i.e. mapped to physically available RAM and disk blocks, which are shared between all running processes.

Comment: Also check Doron's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is. If you load functions in a Dll (`LoadLibrary`) or a .so (`dlopen`). You will deallocate the function when you call `FreeLibrary` or `dlclose` respectively.